# List<T>.FindIndex for multiple results?

Tags: c#

let's say, we have a List with

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
lst.Add(20);
lst.Add(10);
lst.Add(30);
lst.Add(10);
lst.Add(90);
```

If I need to get the index of the first element that is 20 I would use

```
FindIndex()
```

But is there a method which can be used for multiple results?
Let's say I would like to have the index of elements having the number 10.

I know there is a method FindAll() but this gives me a new List insted of the indexes.

The best(?) method would be to get an array of indexes.

Comment: I wonder why you need the indices.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The biggest downside of the following code is that it uses -1 as a magic number, but in case of indexes it's harmless.

```
var indexes = lst.Select((element, index) => element == 10 ? index : -1).
    Where(i => i >= 0).
    ToArray();
```

Answer (score 7):

One possible solution is this:

```
var indexes = lst.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })
                 .Where(v => v.Item == 10)
                 .Select(v => v.Index)
                 .ToArray();
```

First you select all items and their index, then you filter on the item and finally you select the indexes

**Update:** If you want to encapsulate either my or Eve's solution you could use something like

```
public static class ListExtener
{
    public static List<int> FindAllIndexes<T>(this List<T> source, T value)
    {
        return source.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index })
                        .Where(v => v.Item.Equals(value))
                        .Select(v => v.Index)
                        .ToList();
    }
}
```

And then you'd use something like:

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
lst.Add(20);
lst.Add(10);
lst.Add(30);
lst.Add(10);
lst.Add(90);


lst.FindAllIndexes(10)
    .ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: I do think the solution provided by Eve will perform better though, but posted mine as a way to show you to think step by step at first

Comment: checkout [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) for another example using the same approach

Answer (score 2):

Just to give yet another solution:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, lst.Count).Where(i => lst[i] == 10)
```

And of course it can be made an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> FindAllIndices<T>(this IList<T> source, T value)
{
  return Enumerable.Range(0, source.Count)
    .Where(i => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(source[i], value));
}
```